# Slow Connection/DNS/Website?

Tags: domain-name-system, slow-connection

We have a new site setup at seonky.com. As it's a new site the number of users on the site is nothing that big, however we have already resized our server to try and resolve instances of poor performance. It does not look to me that the server is slow due to the site or database, and frankly should not be at this stage, however it looks to be slow due to response time from the DNS or within the time from the DNS to the server.

Is there a way to test if it's your connection, or the request time from the DNS, or something on the way to the server? This is a bit of a wait within the connection time it looks like before it switches over to receiving the content.

Thanks for any feedback,

Answer (score 0):

Timing out the DNS response time is fairly easy with `dig` or `nslookup`.

You may want to look at [Speed Tools](http://code.google.com/speed/tools.html) from Google Code for a good list of web performance testing utilities and guides.

Comment: The Google Speed Tools are really high level. It sounds to me like the OP has connectivity issues, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon [netalyzr](http://netalyzr.icsi.berkeley.edu/index.html). It tests all sorts of things to test your connection, including how fast/slow the DNS resolver takes to resolve names. It not only measures the time it takes the DNS resolver to return a result to you, but also how long it takes the DNS resolver to request the information from their DNS servers. It uses unique domain names for every test, so it won't rely on the resolver's cache: something that's harder to test with just dig or nslookup

It'll also test other things with your DNS resolver that could affect some cases, like ensuring that it falls back to TCP when needed, and whether it can receive larger responses.